# Remove special characters from array elements and mix it with another array

Tags: robotframework

I apologize if this is repeated, but I'm total noob with Robot framework, and I would need help. I have two arrays, results from database:

```
@{users}=   query   Select * from users
@{fieldNames}=   query  SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'robot_test' AND TABLE_NAME = 'users';
```

Results that I get from this are:

```
@{users}= (1, 'user1', 'pass1', 'admin'), (2, 'user2', 'pass2', 'user')
@{fieldNames} = [ ('id',) | ('username',) | ('password',) | ('role',) ]
```

I would like to filter `@(fieldNames)`    to become

```
@{fieldNames} = [ 'id','username','password','role']
```

And then to mix it with `@(users)` to get

```
@{mixedArray}=  (('id',1) , ('username','user1'), ('password','pass1'), ('role','admin')), (('id',2) , ('username','user2'), ('password','pass2'), ('role','user'))
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks everyone for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because database library returns query results as a list of tuples, you can just iterate through them. Only cleaning I did was to use Combine Lists to get rid of tuples inside fieldNames list.

```
*** Settings ***
# Library         Dialogs
Library         Collections
Library         DatabaseLibrary
library         pymysql

*** Variables ***
@{database}     pymysql     users    root    df478444    localhost  3306

*** Test Cases ***
Stackoverflow
    Connect To Database    @{database}
    @{users}=              query   Select * from Users
    @{fieldNames}=         query  SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'users' AND TABLE_NAME = 'Users';
    @{fields list}=        Combine Lists   @{fieldNames}
    @{mixedArray}=         Create List

    :FOR   ${user}    IN    @{users}
    \      ${user row}=      parse user    ${user}    ${fields list}
    \      Append To List    ${mixedArray}    ${user row}
    Log    ${mixedArray}

*** Keywords ***
Parse User
    [Arguments]        ${user}    ${fields}
    @{line}=           Create List
    ${list length}=    Get Length    ${fields}
    :FOR     ${i}    IN RANGE    ${list length}
    \   @{pair}=          Create List
    \   ${f}=             Get From List    ${fields}    ${i}
    \   ${u}=             Get From List    ${user}      ${i}
    \   Append To List    ${pair}    ${f}
    \   Append To List    ${pair}    ${u}
    \   Append To List    ${line}    ${pair}
    Return From Keyword   ${line}
```